# Typeahead Angular JS: Show results on focus after input blur

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bootstrap-typeahead, angular-ui-typeahead

[Codepen demo](http://codepen.io/knitevision1/pen/xZyyMz)

As you notice, if you get `typeahead` to display any results, after you blur out the input the `ng-repeat` of the queries gets cleared out.
Whilst I want it to hide but stay there so as it could be instantly shown again on refocus of the `input`.

How to get `typeahead` not to clear the `ng-repeat` list?

[Exact demo of functionality I am trying to achieve](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/)

1. Enter any letter
2. Blur out the input
3. Focus it again, relevant search results will instantly appear.

It's different from codepen I linked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Editing the `dismissClickHandler` in the following way works around the problem.

```
var dismissClickHandler = function (evt) {
    if (element[0] !== evt.target) {
        resetMatches();
        scope.$digest();
    } else if (element.val().length) {
        element.focus();
        hasFocus = true;
        getMatchesAsync(element.val());
    }
};
```

Comment: You should not edit library source code. It will make it harder to update it later.

Comment: @dfsq well, yes, but creating a real solution for this in the controller can take much more time than logging the changes someone made to the library so that it's easier to edit the library when you updated. In this case, it's true.